# Loop through array elements and substract values if keys are the same

Tags: php, arrays

I am looping through two arrays called $result_start and $result_end arrays.

There are 2 cases here:

1) If arrays have same keys -> substract values (no problem here)

Let's say:

```
$result_start[18]['fld_IndActive1Imp'] = 100;
$result_start[5]['fld_IndActive1Imp'] = 100;

$result_end[18]['fld_IndActive1Imp'] = 250;
$result_end[5]['fld_IndActive1Imp'] = 300;
```

So values should be

```
$consumptions[0] => 150  // result_end - result_start (for key #18)
$consumptions[1] => 200 // result_end - result_start (for key #5)
```

In this case the code I wrote is below and works fine:

```
if (!array_diff_key($result_start, $result_end) && !array_diff_key($result_end, $result_start)) {
        for ($index = 0; $index < count($result_start); $index++) {
            $consumptions[$index]['active1_imp'] = $result_end[$index]['fld_IndActive1Imp'] - $result_start[$index]['fld_IndActive1Imp'];
        }
}
```

2) If 1 array have more keys then the other (having problems)

For example let's say arrays an values are like below:

```
$result_start[18]['fld_IndActive1Imp'] = 100;
$result_start[5]['fld_IndActive1Imp'] = 100;

$result_end[5]['fld_IndActive1Imp'] = 300;
```

In this case, consumptions should be,

```
$consumptions[0] => 0 // // No end value for key #18 so it's 0
$consumptions[1] => 200 // result_end - result_start (for key #5)
```

I'm having problems writing second case. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```
if (count($result_start) > count($result_end)) { // start > end
    $index = 0;
    foreach ($result_start as $start) {
        if (!array_key_exists($start['fld_DeviceId'], $result_end)) { // yoksa 
            $consumptions[$index]['active1_imp'] = 0;
        } else {
            $consumptions[$index]['active1_imp'] = $result_end[$start['fld_DeviceId']]['fld_IndActive1Imp'] - $start['fld_IndActive1Imp'];
        }
        $index++;
    }
} else { // end > start
    $index = 0;
    foreach ($result_end as $end) {
        if (!array_key_exists($end['fld_DeviceId'], $result_start)) { // yoksa
            $consumptions[$index]['active1_imp'] = 0;
        } else {
            $consumptions[$index]['active1_imp'] = $end['fld_IndActive1Imp'] - $result_start[$end['fld_DeviceId']]['fld_IndActive1Imp'];
        }
        $index++;
    }
}
```

Comment: this what i have  mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 0):

you have to check whether the index in set in the second array

try this

```
$consumptions[$index]['active1_imp'] = (isset($result_end[$index]['fld_IndActive1Imp']) ? $result_end[$index]['fld_IndActive1Imp'] - $result_start[$index]['fld_IndActive1Imp'] : 0;
```